# ¿Cómo se pueden ordenar los elementos de una lista que está dentro de otra en un orden específico en Python?

Tags: python, lista

Voy a intentar explicarme mejor.

Supongamos que es un control de entradas y salidas de stock de una frutería por ejemplo.

Esta es la lista que necesito ordenar, cuyos elementos deben ir en un orden específico:

**Lista inicial:**

```
[[5, 9, 5.0, 0.0, '11-02-23', 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0],
[6, 9, 3.0, 0.0, '11-02-23', 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0],
[7, 9, 0.0, 2.0, '11-02-23', 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0]]
```

Esta lista, se retroalimenta de una consulta a una tabla de una base de datos sqlite de la que obtiene, por un lado, los 4 primeros índices de cada sublista y a la que se le añaden, por otro lado, otros 3 de otra consulta a otra tabla a cada sublista.

La longitud de la lista principal puede ser variable, dependiendo del número de entradas registradas en la base de datos, en este caso supongamos que tengo 3, pero podría ir creciendo.

**La lista final debería quedar algo así:**

```
[[5, 9, Frutas, Fresas, 14.0, 5.0, 0.0, '11-02-23'],
[6, 9, Frutas, Fresas, 19.0, 3.0, 0.0, '11-02-23'], 
[7, 9, Frutas, Fresas, 16.0, 0.0, 2.0, '11-02-23']
```

Se trata de cambiar el orden de los elementos de las sublistas para cada sublista dentro de la lista principal, en función del número de entradas registradas, la cual arrojaría varias sublistas con sus correspondientes elementos.

No se si me he explicado bien, ya que es un poco enrevesado y de lo que uno tiene en la cabeza a lo que trata de explicar, puede haber una gran diferencia.

He mirado por el camino de 'sort' 'key', pero no logro sacar nada parecido, en el foro tampoco he encontrado nada similar.

Estaré encantado de dar más datos o aportar más detalles si los necesitáis.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda. ;)

Comment: Pero ¿cuál es el orden deseado de cada sublista? ¿Se basa en los valores que contiene o solo se trata de reordenar los elementos que están en cierta posición para que estén en otra? Por ejemplo, si numeramos los índices de una tus subilstas como [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] (pues tienen todas ocho elementos) veo que tus resultados usarían en cambio el orden [0,1,5,6,7,2,3,4], es decir, se trata de "mover" los últimos 3 elementos para que queden después del segundo. ¿Es esto?

Comment: Si correcto!, seria así en este caso concreto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como solución genérica, que permite variar el orden deseado simplemente modificando una variable, se me ocurre tener ese orden deseado en una lista que actúa como "configuración" de la ordenación deseada. En tu caso supongo que esa lista debería tener los siguientes valores:

```
orden_deseado = [0,1,5,6,7,2,3,4]
```

Los números son los índices de tu sublista original. Así que esto estaría diciendo que se quieren primero los dos primeros elementos de la sublista (los de índice 0 y 1) después los tres últimos (índices 5,6,7) y finalmente los que quedaban (índices 2,3,4).

El bucle que propongo sería este:

```
for sublist in lista:
  sublist[:] = [sublist[i] for i in orden_deseado]
```

Si se aplica sobre la lista de ejemplo que dabas, el resultado que sale es:

```
[[5, 9, 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0, 5.0, 0.0, '11-02-23'],
 [6, 9, 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0, 3.0, 0.0, '11-02-23'],
 [7, 9, 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0, 0.0, 2.0, '11-02-23']]
```

La gracia del método es que variando el valor de `orden_deseado` puedes especificar cualquier otro orden. Así que esto podría ser una función que reciba el orden como parámetro:

```
def reordenar_sublistas(lista, orden):
  for sublist in lista:
    sublist[:] = [sublist[i] for i in orden]

lista = [[5, 9, 5.0, 0.0, '11-02-23', 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0], [6, 9, 3.0, 0.0, '11-02-23', 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0], [7, 9, 0.0, 2.0, '11-02-23', 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0]]
reordenar_sublistas(lista, [0,1,5,6,7,2,3,4])
print(lista)
```

Nota: La función `reordenar_sublistas()` no retorna nada, porque modifica el orden de los elementos *in-place*.

Comment: Perfecto! es la solución que andaba buscando! Muchas gracias @abulafia

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = [
    [5, 9, 5.0, 0.0, '11-02-23', 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0], 
    [6, 9, 3.0, 0.0, '11-02-23', 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0], 
    [7, 9, 0.0, 2.0, '11-02-23', 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0]
]

sal = []
for sublista in lista:
    sal.append( sublista[0:2] + sublista[5:7] + sublista[7:8] + sublista[2:3] + sublista[3:4] + sublista[4:5] )
    
lista = sal
print(lista)
```

esto nos imprime:

```
[
    [5, 9, 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0, 5.0, 0.0, '11-02-23'], 
    [6, 9, 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0, 3.0, 0.0, '11-02-23'], 
    [7, 9, 'Frutas', 'Fresas', 14.0, 0.0, 2.0, '11-02-23']
]
```

Si bien mi solución es "correcta", como me indicó @DanteS., se puede simplificar, cambiando:

```
sublista[0:2] + sublista[5:7] + sublista[7:8] + sublista[2:3] + sublista[3:4] + sublista[4:5]   

por  

sublista[:2] + sublista[5:8] + sublista[2:5]
```

Mi respuesta está inspirada en la de @UlisesAntonioChávez, que me indicó el camino.

Solo como curiosidad, agrego otra forma de obtener el resultado:

```
for sub in lista:
   for i in range( 2, len( sub ) - 3):
       item = sub[ i ]
       sub[ i ] = sub[ i + 3 ]
       sub[ i + 3 ] = item

print(lista)
```

Por el comentario de @rgmagritte, me doy cuenta de lo difícil de digerir de mi respuesta, voy a tratar de explicarla.
En principio, al contrario que la excelente solución de @Abulafia, este método no es genérico, solo vale para este ejemplo.
Observeamos la entrada y la salida esperada:

posiciones:

| 1° | 2° | 3° | 4° | 5° | 6° | 7° | 8° |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 9 | 5.0 | 0.0 | '11-02-23' | 'Frutas' | 'Fresas' | 14.0 |
| 5 | 9 | 'Frutas' | 'Fresas' | 14.0 | 5.0 | 0.0 | '11-02-23' |

nos encontramos con lo siguiente:
el 1° y 2° item, conservan la posición.
el 3° va a la la 6° y el 6° va a la 3°.
el 4° va a la la 7° y el 7° va a la 4°.
el 5° va a la la 8° y el 8° va a la 5°.

esto nos permite usar el mecanismo de algoritmo de la burbuja, de almacenar en una variable auxiliar el valor de una posición, para intercambiar los valores de ambas:

```
   aux = array[ posicionA ]
   array[ posicionA ] = array[ posicionB ]
   array[ posicionB ] = item
```

dada la peculiaridad de este escenario, en el que la distancia entre los item's que se quieren intercambiar es fija, y que las distintas permutaciones están escalonadas, podemos metertodo en un for a fin de evitar escribir lo siguiente:

```
for sublista in lista:
    item2 = sublista[ 2 ]
    item3 = sublista[ 3 ]
    item4 = sublista[ 4 ]
    item5 = sublista[ 5 ]
    item6 = sublista[ 6 ]
    item7 = sublista[ 7 ]
    sublista[ 2 ] = item5
    sublista[ 3 ] = item6
    sublista[ 4 ] = item7
    sublista[ 5 ] = item2
    sublista[ 6 ] = item3
    sublista[ 7 ] = item4
```

espero haber aclarado el funcionamiento de tan abstruso método.

Comment: Sería más rapido y crearías menos listas intermedias si juntas algunos slices: `sublista[:2] + sublista[5:8] + sublista[2:5]`. Ten en cuenta que cuando concatenas dos listas, se crea una nueva lista.

Comment: @DanteS., no puedo ser más bruto!!! gracias por la corrección, deberías ponerla como respuesta!!!.

Comment: Gracias por la propuesta! Pero es muy poca diferencia respecto a tu respuesta. Si la hiciera, sería un plagio. Tampoco digo que lo "corrijas" (no está mal lo que escribiste, da el mismo resultado).

Comment: @DanteS. entonces corrijo en tu nombre.

Comment: Está bien, muchas gracias! Por cierto, un detalle curioso: la solución de ulises modifica las listas in-place (es decir, modifica las listas originales), mientras que tu solución crea nuevas listas.

Comment: @DanteS., agregué un nuevo método, me gustaría saber tu opinión.

Comment: Está bueno también! Solo dos cosas que decir. Primero, que le serviría al OP solo si su verdadero plan es intercambiar las posiciones `i` e `i+3` estando i en `range(2, len(sub) - 3)`. Y segundo, podrías mejorarlo usando unpacking: `sub[i], sub[i + 3] = sub[i + 3], sub[i]`. Por cierto, si estás interesado en hablar con alguien bueno en Python, mi opinión es que Abulafia me supera y es el mejor en Python y respuestas (al menos, durante mis 3 años en el sitio). No pensé que llegaría tan lejos en este sitio cuando empecé, y es un honor c:

Comment: @DanteS., gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para responderme, no se si es buena o mala la implementación (hablando de velocidad), de ahí mi pregunta, ten por seguro que cumple con lo que el OP pide (si bien se me puede deslizar un error, pruebo antes de subir), y si, le tengo mucho respeto a Abulafia, tambien a Candid, y tu estás ahí, peleando palmo a palmo, me considero alumno tuyo y de Candid (a Abulafia no lo cruzo nunca).

Comment: Supongo que en velocidad, la mejor opción es crear una nueva lista e ir metiendo valores con extend o modificar in-place. Yo también pruebo siempre que puedo hago pruebas, es una forma de asegurarse de que no haya errores. No entendí a que te refieres con "palmo a palmo". Gracias! Es un honor ayudar a tu aprendisaje, ayudar a todos aquí, y veo que me fui ganando una buena reputacion (no solo en forma de numero) aquí nwn

Comment: @DanteS., palmo a palmo = cabeza a cabeza, están peleando por el trono.

Comment: En primer lugar muchas gracias a todos por las soluciones aportadas y el "brainstorming" posterior, la verdad es que con la poca experiencia que tengo aún en Python, estoy abrumado. 
En cualquier caso, me quedo con la solución de @Abulafia puesto que inicialmente ya tenia en mente poder encontrar algo así, es decir, un orden especificado previamente por los índices. 
Simplemente quiero daros las gracias a todos una vez mas por vuestra ayuda que en esta ocasión ha sido un gran aporte y de gran utilidad para mi, tratare de probar las soluciones y sus variantes y sobre todo de comprenderlas. ;)

Comment: @MarcePuente, en realidad la parte inicial estaba suficientemente clara, pero en cualquier caso gracias por la aclaración. Tu solución es simple y además cumple con lo que pedía, aunque he de reconocer que a nivel practico la de abulafia me permite mas flexibilidad, además, ese tipo de idea la tenia en la cabeza pero no sabia como implementarla. En cualquier caso, muchas gracias también por tu aporte, lo veo mas lógico de implementar, la verdad es que no se como no se me ocurrió una solución similar... supongo que será porque aun me faltan "horas de vuelo". Lo dicho: muchas gracias también